# Is measurement uncertainty 2 times standard deviation or 2 times standard error?

Tags: sensor, error, accuracy, statistics, uncertainty

Textbooks and online sources often say the industry standard for uncertainty is given at a confidence interval of 95 %. This means out of 100 measurements, 95 would achieve the specified value and deviate around this value in range of the +/- uncertainty given. For example temperature sensor: states uncertainty of 1 deg C within a certain range. So 95% of the time the uncertainty is within this range.

However i am not sure how this uncertainty is calculated. Is the uncertainty 2 times standard deviation or 2 times standard error?

[image]

If for example a temperature sensor says it measures temperature with an uncertainty of +/- 1 deg C, then did the manufacturer test this sensor say a thousand times at a controlled temperature, for example 25 C,   calculated the mean to be 25 C of those 1000 measurements, and then give this uncertainty as +/- 2 times standard deviation/standard error to get the final uncertainty of +/- 1 deg C ?

Here is the source of the formulas and uncertainty explanantion: https://andyjconnelly.wordpress.com/2017/05/16/uncertainty-and-repeats/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many standard deviations is Sensor / Component Uncertainty (+/- X) given in?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540634/how-many-standard-deviations-is-sensor-component-uncertainty-x-given-in)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540659/how-to-calculate-measurement-uncertainty-of-my-pressure-sensor-circuit And all three from the same OP.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thats me, still trying to figure it out. If the distribution is assumed to be gaussian then according to sources from metrology books and the link i posted, then manufacturer uncertainty or measurement uncertainty is given in a 95% confidence interval from the gaussian curve. So do you have any answers to the question? its different to my other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can depend on the manufacturer how well they actually measure their limits for guarantees. Usually the actual methodology is not documented in great detail, though they may have some type of general documentation. I've done the measurements for a few of these lines on datasheets. Basically, it is a guarantee by the manufacturer that the value will fall within the limits. Usually what's at stake is mainly the manufacturer's reputation -- there is often a clause somewhere that they will not be liable for other damages, though major customers do sometimes ask for big payments if they need to upgrade equipment in the field because a batch of parts was out of spec.

The simplest case is when the parameter is tested at production. In that case, we normally calculate the 6-sigma reproducibility and the 6-sigma repeatability errors and use those margins, often padding more to a round number. Reproducibility errors are based on testing on different testers and using different test boards/sites. Repeatability errors are based on repeating the test on the same part multiple times (often re-inserting into the socket).

The somewhat trickier parameters are ones that are not possible to measure at production test. Often this is because it takes too long to measure (e.g., sweeping temperature after packaging) or we don't have the right instruments on the tester. We have to measure these in the lab using slower methods (e.g., sweeping temperature 1 part at a time). Again, we often use 6-sigma margins on measurements, but this can sometimes be much more than you would think. For example, if the part has a type of internal comparison that runs once every clock period, we calculate how many times it would run at max speed over 10 years, and then extrapolate/calculate so that less than 1 part sold per million would fail *once* in that 10 years (1 ppm is actually a bit better than 6-sigma). That extreme example is really only if this type of failure would cause the part to become useless (e.g., requiring a power cycle).

The above is what we do for a "competitive" parameter -- one that distinguishes our part from the competition and is the reason somewhat would choose our part. If it's a parameter that is not very important, we sometimes use much larger margins just in case we did something wrong (e.g., missing some cause of variation). That way we don't get returns for parameters that we don't really care much about.

The other main strategy for specifying competitive parameters (like if the competitor is not using such a rigorous method) is to put a footnote that says exactly what is meant, e.g., "3-sigma in condition X with N=100." That's more of a marketing decision than an engineering one though.

Comment: Thanks Justin, did i understand correctly that uncertainty can be given in confidence intervals of a gaussian distribution? and usually the confidence interval is k = 2 which is 95%? and the uncertainty is k * standard deviation ? as such the uncertainty of anything (sensor or component or measurement) is given as +/- 2 standard deviations which means 95% C.I. which means 95% of the time the results will be in this uncertainty range?

Comment: Uncertainty *can* be given using confidence intervals (though not all distributions are gaussian). However, that is *not* what min/max limits on a datasheet normally mean. Min/Max limits mean that you can assume the value is between the min and the max with 100% confidence. It's the manufacturer's job to make it so. Some manufacturers are not as careful as others though -- that's why choosing a reputable manufacturer is important.

Comment: So how would one go about determining the uncertainty when developing a senor? Do you have any tips for books / links which outline the process of doing this from the ground up? Im asking in relation to another post i made, on how to determine uncertainty for a self made sensor: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540659/how-to-calculate-measurement-uncertainty-of-my-pressure-sensor-circuit

Comment: OK, that's a pretty different case. I don't have a good book, I sort of learned it over time. I'll comment there.